# Construct arp packet and send it to local linux but no reply

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, arp

I construct ARP packet with random ip and MAC address(.e.g. 172.29.26.152 and 0x52,0x54,0x4C,0x00,0x08,0x00).
Run the program on my pc. 
So the program sends the packet to my own NIC( ip: 172.29.26.102 ) eth0 to get its MAC address.
But I receive no reply from eth0.
I use `tcpdump -i lo -n -XX` and no packets appear. I can get the packet constructed using `tcpdump -i eth0 host 172.29.26.152 -n -XX`.
Why host doesn't reply? Thank you very much!

code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void packarp(char *mymac, char *tarmac, int *tarip, int *myip, char *opcode, char *arppack)
{
    char eth_type[2] = {0x00,0x01};   
    char por_type[2] = {0x08,0x00};     
    char type[2] = {0x08, 0x06};        
    char eth_length = 6;        
    char por_length = 4;        

    memset(arppack, 0, 42);                 
    memcpy(arppack, tarmac, 6);             
    memcpy(arppack + 6, mymac, 6);          
    memcpy(arppack + 12, type, 2);         
    memcpy(arppack + 14, eth_type, 2);    
    memcpy(arppack + 16, por_type, 2);      
    memcpy(arppack + 18, &eth_length, 1);   
    memcpy(arppack + 19, &por_length, 1);   
    memcpy(arppack + 20, opcode, 2);        
    memcpy(arppack + 22, mymac, 6);          
    memcpy(arppack + 28, myip, 4);          
    if (!(opcode[0] == 0x00 && opcode[1] == 0x01)) {
        memcpy(arppack + 32, tarmac, 6);        
    }
    memcpy(arppack + 38, tarip, 4);         
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char mymac[6] = {0x52,0x54,0x4C,0x00,0x08,0x00};
    char tarmac[6] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
    char recvarp[42] = {0};
    char sendarp[42] = {0};
    int tarip;
    int myip;
    char opcode[2];
    int sock_fd,p;
    struct sockaddr addr;

    if (argc < 4) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    myip = inet_addr(argv[3]);
    tarip = inet_addr(argv[2]);
    opcode[0] = 0x00;
    opcode[1] = 0x01;

    packarp(mymac, tarmac, &tarip, &myip, opcode, sendarp);

    if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
        perror("Open Socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    strncpy(addr.sa_data, argv[1], sizeof(addr.sa_data));
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);


    while(1) {
        if (sendto(sock_fd, sendarp, 42, 0, &addr, len) == 42) {
            for(p = 0; p < 42;p++)
              {
                printf("%02x ",(unsigned char)sendarp[p]);
              }
            printf(".\nSend ARP packet successful.\n\n");
        } else {
            perror("sendto");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (recvfrom(sock_fd, recvarp, 42, 0, &addr, &len) == 42) {
            if (!memcmp((void *)recvarp + 28, (void *)sendarp + 38, 4)) {
                memcpy(tarmac, recvarp + 22, 6);
                printf("Succeed to get MAC address.\n");
                break;
            }
        }


        for(p = 0; p < 42;p++)
              {
                printf("%02x ",(unsigned char)recvarp[p]);
              }
        printf(".\n\n");

        sleep(1);
    }

    opcode[0] = 0x00;
    opcode[1] = 0x01;
    packarp(mymac, tarmac, &tarip, &myip, opcode, sendarp);

    while(1) {
        if (sendto(sock_fd, sendarp, 42, 0, &addr, len) == 42) {
            for(p = 0; p < 42;p++)
              {
                printf("%02x ",(unsigned char)sendarp[p]);
              }
            printf("Succeed to send ARP Spoofing. \n");
        } else {
            perror("sendto");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(sock_fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and it is able to send and receive ARP packets to/from remote machines. The problem is you are trying to send the ARP request for local IP address.

The created ARP request passed to network driver and sent to physical layer. Network driver handles the packet as outgoing packet it is just send. A switch or whatever device at the other end of the wire does not forward the ARP request back to the interface where it was received.

So local OS never receives the ARP request and it cannot respond. tcpdump catches and shows the outgoing ARP request. There is no incoming one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I don't know much about networking.Actually,I have a virtual machine but not VirtualBox or VMWare.It just can do some simple things.I tried to add network to realize the networking function.So I run my VM on host PC. A 3.18 linux kernel run in my VM. Network is connected to PHY module. As PHY module is realized by socket, I simulate the code above.

Comment: According to what you said above, is it impossible for host pc and my VM to get MAC address from  each other? That is why Vbox or VMware needs bridge or NAT or hostonly mode?So Socket is not the right way or not useful enough at least to make VM and host connected? I need to realize HostOnly at least? Now Ping doesn't work between each other because of receiving no arp reply.  Can you give me some suggestion that I can ping from one to the other one? The VM can ping anywhere but host PC now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure how your VM and your hypervisor work but in general the hypervisor running on host creates a virtual network device and the hypervisor forwards traffic between then guest OS and the virtual network device in the host. The manner how does hypervisor forward the traffic is usually configurable in the hypervisor and you can set options like NAT, bridge, host-only and others - it depends on hypervisor.